# Append values dynamically by iterating over source pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns in it.

```
df_levels = ["No","window1_level","window2_level","window3_level","window4_level", "window5_level"]
```

Source dataframe:

```
df_source = pd.DataFrame([[111111,123,103,"window1","window2"], [333333,104,123,"window3","window4"], [678698,111,144,"window1","window5"]], columns=['No','level1','level2','value1','value2'])


No       level1        level2       value1      value2
111111      123          103        window1     window2
333333      104          123        window3     window4
678698      111          144        window1     window5
```

Result dataframe:

df_result:

```
 No   window1_level window2_level window3_level window4_level window5_level 
 111111      123       103                 
 333333                               104          123
 678698      111                                              144
```

I am looping through the source dataframe and assign values to the result dataframe (df_result). After assignment, I am not sure on how to append these values to df_result as the row['value1'] and row['value2'] will change depend on the values in df_source.

```
for index, row in df_source.iterrows():
 df_result["No"] = row['No']
 df_t2[str(row['value1'])+"_level"] = row['level1']
 df_t2[str(row['value2'])+"_level"] = row['level2']
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dont iterate in pandas, if exist some vectorized alternatives, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758).

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df_source.reset_index(), 
                     stubnames=['level', 'value'],
                     i=['index','No'],
                     j='tmp').reset_index()

df = df.pivot('No','value','level')
print (df)
value   window1  window2  window3  window4  window5
No                                                 
111111    123.0    103.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
333333      NaN      NaN    104.0    123.0      NaN
678698    111.0      NaN      NaN      NaN    144.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through `df_source` and append the new values to a separate list, then concatenate the values in the list to get `df_result`. You can try doing this:

```
result = []
for _, row in df_source.iterrows():  # Ignore index because not needed
    value1, level1 = row['value1'], row['level1']
    value2, level2 = row['value2'], row['level2']
    
    # Append as a list of dictionaries
    result.append({
        "No": row['No'],
        value1 + "_level": level1,
        value2 + "_level": level2
    })    

# Concatenate everything into a DataFrame
df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

This results in:

```
    No      window1_level   window2_level   window3_level   window4_level   window5_level
0   111111  123.0           103.0           NaN             NaN             NaN
1   333333  NaN             NaN             104.0           123.0           NaN
2   678698  111.0           NaN             NaN             NaN             144.0
```

Depending on what you need, you can replace the `NaN` with whatever values you need, e.g. 0:

```
df_result.fillna(0)
```